# Using Delphi XE to scan a Subversion SVN Repository (without a local copy)

Tags: delphi, svn, tortoisesvn, delphi-xe

I am looking for an example or component which allows Delphi to scan a SVN repo for a certain filename (with wildcards). Example: bob*.txt

Does anyone know the best method for this?

Comment: There's no way to "scan a SVN repo for a certain filename", which is why TortoiseSVN doesn't have a "find" or "search" option. You can scan working copies (folders on a drive) using normal command line methods or search using Windows Explorer, or from code using `IOUtils.TDirectory.GetFiles`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`svn list`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.list.html) command will list the files in whatever repo you give it. It doesn't have to be local. Use the `-R` option to list recursively, and search the output for whatever names you want.